# BottomTabNavigator - react native

Tags: react-native

I want to have bottomTabNavigator in my app,I have installed the followings:

```
>     "react-navigation": "^4.0.7",
>     "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5",
```

then i have created a TabNavigator like:

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import VideosScreen from "../screens/VideosScreen";

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Videos: VideosScreen
  },
  {
    mode: "modal"
  }
);

const VideosStack = createStackNavigator({
  Videos: VideosScreen,
  Video: VideosScreen
});

const FoodsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Foods: VideosScreen,
  Food: VideosScreen
});
const TrainingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Trainings: VideosScreen,
  Training: VideosScreen
});

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  VideosStack
});

export default TabNavigator;
```

and, then i have created an AppNavigator:

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import VideosScreen from "../screens/VideosScreen";
import TabNavigator from "./TabNavigator";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Videos: VideosScreen
  },
  {
    mode: "modal"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

now when i run the application it crashes as you can see in the picture below:
[image]

now what can i do? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on an older React Native version, you need to manually link the dependencies. To do that,

run on terminal:

```
react-native link react-native-reanimated
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
react-native link react-native-screens
```

or if you are using expo, run:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

Comment: thanks a lot Krishna, i used "expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated" and it worked.